# Rails Cucumber Path Mapping Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'm new to Cucumber and Capybara, and I'm having a really hard time understanding how to get the paths set up the right way. I'm getting this error when running my cucumber tests about not finding a mapping to the edit page for "Alien"....but I defined the edit_movie_path, so I don't see where it's getting tripped up.

Here's a feature file called search_for_directors.featur

```
Feature: Search for movies by director

  As a movie buff
  So that I can find movies with my favorite director
  I want to include and serach on director information in movies I enter

Background: movies in database

  Given the following movies exist:
  | title        | rating | director     | release_date |
  | Star Wars    | PG     | George Lucas |   1977-05-25 |
  | Blade Runner | PG     | Ridley Scott |   1982-06-25 |
  | Alien        | R      |              |   1979-05-25 |
  | THX-1138     | R      | George Lucas |   1971-03-11 |

Scenario: add director to existing movie
  When I go to the edit page for "Alien"
  And  I fill in "Director" with "Ridley Scott"
  And  I press "Update Movie Info"
  Then the director of "Alien" should be "Ridley Scott"

Scenario: find movie with same director
  Given I am on the details page for "Star Wars"
  When  I follow "Find Movies With Same Director"
  Then  I should be on the Similar Movies page for "Star Wars"
  And   I should see "THX-1138"
  But   I should not see "Blade Runner"

Scenario: can't find similar movies if we don't know director (sad path)
  Given I am on the details page for "Alien"
  Then  I should not see "Ridley Scott"
  When  I follow "Find Movies With Same Director"
  Then  I should be on the home page
  And   I should see "'Alien' has no director info"
```

Now here's movie_steps.rb

```
Given(/^the following movies exist:$/) do |table|
  table.hashes.each do |movie|
  # table is a Cucumber::Ast::Table
    Movie.create(movie)
  end
end
```

And here's web_steps.rb

```
When(/^I go to the edit page for "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1|
  debugger
  visit path_to(edit_movie_path(arg1))
end
```

Finally, here's paths.rb

```
module NavigationHelpers
  # Maps a name to a path. Used by the
  #
  #   When /^I go to (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  #
  # step definition in web_steps.rb
  #
  def path_to(page_name)
    case page_name

    when /^the (RottenPotatoes )?home\s?page$/ then '/movies'
    when /^the movies page$/ then '/movies'

    when /the edit page for "(.*)"$/
      edit_movie_path(Movie.find_by_title($1)[:id])

    # Add more mappings here.
    # Here is an example that pulls values out of the Regexp:
    #
    #   when /^(.*)'s profile page$/i
    #     user_profile_path(User.find_by_login($1))

    else
      begin
        page_name =~ /^the (.*) page$/
        path_components = $1.split(/\s+/)
        self.send(path_components.push('path').join('_').to_sym)
      rescue NoMethodError, ArgumentError
        raise "Can't find mapping from \"#{page_name}\" to a path.\n" +
          "Now, go and add a mapping in #{__FILE__}"
      end
    end
  end
end

World(NavigationHelpers)
```

I run the test simply by typing `cucumber`, and I get the error I provided at the top of the post. So at this point I guess I have two questions. Why is this happening/how is my edit_movies_path definition incorrect? And secondly, why do I need to even specify this? If I run `rake routes`, I can see all the usual path aliases, and it sort of seems in contradiction to the philosophy of "convention over configuration" to have to specify something I've already got specified in my routes file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here it is:

Notice your `web_steps`:

```
When(/^I go to the edit page for "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1|
  debugger
  visit path_to(edit_movie_path(arg1))
end
```

You are already supplying `edit_movie_path(arg1)` to `path_to`, where path to is as follow:

```
def path_to(page_name)
    case page_name

    when /^the (RottenPotatoes )?home\s?page$/ then '/movies'
    when /^the movies page$/ then '/movies'

    when /the edit page for "(.*)"$/
      edit_movie_path(Movie.find_by_title($1)[:id])

    else
      begin
        page_name =~ /^the (.*) page$/
        path_components = $1.split(/\s+/)
        self.send(path_components.push('path').join('_').to_sym)
      rescue NoMethodError, ArgumentError
        raise "Can't find mapping from \"#{page_name}\" to a path.\n" +
          "Now, go and add a mapping in #{__FILE__}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

No case in your `case page_name` matches with `edit_movie_path(arg1)` that you are supplying, so it will fall back to the:

```
   else
      begin
        page_name =~ /^the (.*) page$/
        path_components = $1.split(/\s+/)
        self.send(path_components.push('path').join('_').to_sym)
      rescue NoMethodError, ArgumentError
        raise "Can't find mapping from \"#{page_name}\" to a path.\n" +
          "Now, go and add a mapping in #{__FILE__}"
      end
    end
```

part, which splits, and breaks and rejoins your path to what you are seeing.

To fix that, here is what you can do:

Notice that you have a case for:

```
when /the edit page for "(.*)"$/
  edit_movie_path(Movie.find_by_title($1)[:id])
```

This is what you can use to reach the edit page. This is looking for an expression like `the edit page for...`

> Note, change this to include a carat at the front like: `when /^the edit page for "(.*)"$/` The carat means that is the beginning of the expression.

So, in your `web_steps`, refactor your code to something like the following:

```
When(/^I go to the edit page for "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1|
  debugger
  the edit page for arg1
end
```

Hope this is explanatory enough...